# Positioning a <Button> float: right over an <Image>

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using the following code to try and place a "Copy" button over the upper right hand corner of an image :

```
<div className="itemImg">
    <Button icon={<MdContentCopy />} style={{float: 'right'}} onClick={(e) => {copyItem(props.item.name)}} />
    <Image
        className="itemImg"
        src={"/api/feed/"+props.feed+"/"+props.item.name}
        preview={false}
    />
</div>
```

If the  block is a , i.e. not an image, it works as expected, but for some reason, `<Image>` is having an issue, see below. The "Copy" icon should be placed atop the image because of `float: right`

[image]

Our good friend ChatGPT recommends not using `float` and rely on flex layout to do this. Not a big deal and it actually provided the solution, but I'd rather have minimal code and CSS over what antd/react provides natively.

Comment: float certainly is the wrong tool here. float is a tool to float an element within flow-text such as an image in a newspaper. you simply need to absolute position the button to the parent container that neatly fits the image.

Comment: Damn. You're probably right, I don't why this got stuck in my head that it should work on <img>. It works fine over texts though, without flowing the text around the image, like I expected but your comment probably makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the container a `position: absolute` and a `width: min-content` so it fits the image width.
After that you can position the button with `position: absolute`

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
}

.container button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  right: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg">
  <button>Copy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, I just had to get rid of width: min-content; or the image wouldn't be visible for some reason. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

To solve that you need to create a container with `position: relative` and inside the container, you add your image and the button. but the button must have a `position: absolute` and add right and top values.
I have added a snippet, you can change that to your react code using your components it will work the same.

```css
.image {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.copy-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img alt="a goat" class="image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17686105/pexels-photo-17686105/free-photo-of-animal-cute-agriculture-farm.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1">
  <button class="copy-btn">copy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it **must** not have a `top: 10` and `right: 10` (which are invalid units). They can have any size the OP like. For responsiveness, a relative unit should be favored over absolute units. The container is only needed to position the button correctly. As such the image size should matter and the container fit to the image. If you make the image fit the container you either ruin the aspect-ratio of the image or squeeze/stratch it for no rerason.

Comment: I agree about invalid units. I have updated my answer. The decision to use fixed or relative depends on the use case.